# oauth2 Gem for rails consumer How to use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, rubygems, oauth-2.0

I have no idea how to use this [oauth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2)

The Usage Examples confuse me.

In `token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic some_password'})`

Shouldn't 'authorization_code_value' is a part of the response? How could I get it before the request is made?

My code so far:

```
require 'oauth2'
class Apis::OauthsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    client = OAuth2::Client.new('id', 'secrete', :token_url => '/dialog/oauth?', :site => 'https://www.facebook.com')

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000')

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: [], status: :ok }
end
```

end
end

Why `client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000')`
 is not sending request to facebook?

Eventually, I'm not connecting to fb, I just use it as an experiment. That's why I don't use their sdk.

Is there any example I could follow?

Please help!! :(

Comment: I'm looking into this too, but I can't figure out where the example code should go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http:/0') only generates the url.
I still need to redirect_to url.

Stupid me ...